# how to store a photo for a product card in a SQL database and display it using react

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, e-commerce

I am trying to create product cards for an ecommerce style website. I am able to display all the text from the database no problem. name, price, description and whatnot. I am trying now to add a row to my database for my product table for photos that way i can map over the products and have each card with a product picture. However for the life of me I can't figure out how I should store it and have it work and show the picture.

```
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
import { Flex, Text, Button, Image, Box} from "@chakra-ui/react";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import FilterMenu from "../components/filtermenu";



const ProductList = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products');
        setProducts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <Navbar />

    <Text m={4} textAlign='center' fontSize='lg'>Our Product List</Text>
    <FilterMenu />
    <Flex>
      <Flex flexWrap='wrap' justify='space-evenly' ml="220px">
        {products.map(product => (
          <Flex key={product.id} flexDirection="column" mr="4" mb="4" flex={{ base: '0 0 100%', md: '0 0 48%', lg: '0 0 32%' }} p={3} border='1px' borderColor='gray.200'>
            <Text textAlign='center' fontSize='lg'>{product.name}</Text>
            <Text>Price: ${product.price}</Text>
            <Text>Description: {product.description}</Text>
            <Text>Category: {product.category}</Text>
            <Button colorScheme='blue' size='xs'>
            Add to Cart!
            </Button>
          </Flex>
        ))}
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  </>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

I tried to figure out the solutions using chatgpt and I orginally tried to add into the photos column "../resources/EllipticalTrainer.png" aka the file path to get the picture saved on my project and thought I would be able to just do this for each picture and have them display, however this did not work when trying to do
`<Image src={product.photo}>`, all that would show is a little picture icon and if I added an alt the alt text. Is there something I am missing? When also trying to figure out the solution I saw some talk of maybe that I should be comverting the photo to binary data to store in the database however I am not sure the first step in this process as I am still a beginner.

Comment: 1) Add the table definition, as text, to your question text. 2) If I am following correctly you are just storing the file path in the database, correct? If so:  a) What code are you using to fetch the photo from the path? b) Does the user the code runs as have permissions on that path? 3) To store binary data directly in the database see [Binary Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html). Though if you have a lot of photos, especially large ones, then this can greatly increase the size of the database and make backup/restores a good deal longer.